# Justify Quote Text in Github Pages using markdown language?

Tags: github, github-pages

After experimenting with "Github-Pages", using the markdown language, while writing documentation I have been struggling to find documentation regarding the use of -> justifying " Quote Text ", that writes the text from left edge to the right edge and keep it justified for (Pc, Mobile, etc)  Ending the text at the same ending line.

```
 > Quote Text message
```

[image]

[Github Markdown Explaining formating](https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/writing-on-github/getting-started-with-writing-and-formatting-on-github/basic-writing-and-formatting-syntax)

[Github Markdown Cheat Cheat](https://github.com/adam-p/markdown-here/wiki/Markdown-Cheatsheet)

Each source states specifically using either "Div" or "P" paragraphs formatting to add justified text, though with a text quote such an option disables to quote text formatting and makes it a regular Text-Message.

But lacks mentioning formatting about " Quote Text ".

- Generally I have seen about over 40 official documentation pages in regards to GitHub and different websites including "Stack-overflow", that has a similar problem formatting "Quote Text" making it use scroll-bar to see the content and overall unreliable.

Is this an issue or a lacking feature that hasn't been added looking for context or where to find sources regarding the problem

I have tried:

```
<div style="text-align: right"> your-text-here </div>
```

```
<p style='text-align: justify;'> Your Text </p>
```

-Though both will remove the desired "Quote Text" formatting,.
-Assuming it has to be customized formatting outside of the default markdown language.

Any suggestions or sources regarding it?